# How to write a query in MS Access 2007 to display more than one value in more than one column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table.

Table Name:`tblRAC`

```
Examiner Subj scheme pap_code moderator pap_accessed  pap_moderated
Kamble   DTE   EJ1E   12116    mahulkar     25            5
kamble   AEL   DE4E   12110    Patil        2             2
kamble   DTE   CO3C   12064    Nale         37            20
kamble   DTE   IF3E   12064                 01            
Kamble   DTE   IL1E   12116    kulkarni     35            5
```

How to write a query in MS Access 2007 to get output as below.

```
subj    pap_Code   scheme      pap_accessed moderator
DTE      12116    EJ1E,IL1E     60          mahulkar,kulkarni
DTE      12064    CO3C,IF3E     38          Nale
AEL      12110    DE4E          02          Patil

                    Total  100
```

Comment: http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/generic-function-to-concatenate-child-records_topic16&SID=453fabc6-b3z9-34z6zb14-a78f832z-19z89a2c.html    What you want is like a common function usually known as `group_concat`, but Access doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

I actually decided to post this as an answer instead of a comment to make it more easily accessible.

What you want is exactly what other DBMS's provide (which I don't really like to use) that is called `GROUP_CONCAT`. I edited your title to make that more apparent to future searchers(hope you don't mind).

Since Access doesn't support `GROUP_CONCAT` in SQL syntax, you could either write some funky SQL to hope to replicate it or just use VBA.

Below is an example `GROUP CONCAT` VBA function that you can use. found [here](http://blogannath.blogspot.com/2011/01/microsoft-access-tips-tricks-flattening_28.html) (I didn't write it).

```
  Function Concatenate(pstrSQL As String, _
        Optional pstrDelim As String = ", ", _
        Optional pstrLastDelim As String = "") _
        As Variant
'   Created by Duane Hookom, 2003
'   this code may be included in any application/mdb providing
'   this statement is left intact
'   example
'   tblFamily with FamID as numeric primary key
'   tblFamMem with FamID, FirstName, DOB,...
'   return a comma separated list of FirstNames
'   for a FamID
'    John, Mary, Susan

'   ======= in a Query =========================
'   SELECT FamID,
'   Concatenate("SELECT FirstName FROM tblFamMem
'    WHERE FamID =" & [FamID]) as FirstNames
'   FROM tblFamily
'   ============================================

'   to get a return like Duane, Laura, Jake, and Chelsey

'   ======= in a Query =========================
'   SELECT FamID,
'   Concatenate("SELECT FirstName FROM tblFamMem
'    WHERE FamID =" & [FamID], ",",", and ") as FirstNames
'   FROM tblFamily
'   ============================================

'   If FamID is a string rather than numeric,
'    it will need to be delimited with quotes

'   ======= in a Query =========================
'   SELECT FamID,
'   Concatenate("SELECT FirstName FROM tblFamMem
'    WHERE FamID =""" & [FamID] & """", ",",", and ") as FirstNames
'   FROM tblFamily
'   ============================================


'======For DAO uncomment next 4 lines=======
'====== comment out ADO below =======
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(pstrSQL)

'======For ADO uncomment next two lines=====
'====== comment out DAO above ======
    'Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    'length before last concatenation
    Dim intLenB4Last As Integer
    'rs.Open pstrSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, _
    adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    Dim strConcat As String 'build return string
    With rs
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                intLenB4Last = Len(strConcat)
                strConcat = strConcat & _
                .Fields(0) & pstrDelim
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
'====== uncomment next line for DAO ========
    Set db = Nothing
    If Len(strConcat) > 0 Then
        strConcat = Left(strConcat, _
            Len(strConcat) - Len(pstrDelim))
        If Len(pstrLastDelim) > 0 Then
            strConcat = Left(strConcat, _
                intLenB4Last - Len(pstrDelim) - 1) _
                & pstrLastDelim & Mid(strConcat, intLenB4Last + 1)
        End If
    End If
    If Len(strConcat) > 0 Then
        Concatenate = strConcat
     Else
        Concatenate = Null
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Sory i didnt get any thing :(

Comment: You need to create a module in your project and copy paste this code into it. You can then use `Concatenate()` in your queries as the examples show.

Comment: its very tough plzz can u write a module as per my given data